# Is there any option to pass data to SVGImageElement directly?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, d3.js

Having following code, I need to remove href and pass data to svg directly cause now server endpoints are secured so what I want to do is query image endpoint, add oauth2 headers then pass data to svg:

```
node_body_merge
  .select<SVGImageElement>('image')
  .on('contextmenu', function (n: MapNode, i: number) {
    event.preventDefault();
    self.onContextMenu.emit(new NodeContextMenu(event, n));
  })
  .on('dblclick', function (n: MapNode, i: number) {
    event.preventDefault();
    self.onContextConsoleMenu.emit(new NodeContextMenu(event, n));
  })
  .attr('xnode:href', (n: MapNode) => n.symbolUrl)
```

Comment: no but you could make the request yourself in javascript and then write the results as a data URL for the image element to use.

Comment: @RobertLongson could you please explain the second step of your answer, I mean 'write the results as a data URL for the image element to use'

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: Can you give further information on how this is related to Angular?

Comment: you can do this with or without angular.